# Finding the single index of an element in a multidimensional array (number of elements that exist before that element)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Assume we have the following multidimensional array:

```
const myArray = [[[1, 2], 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 10]];
```

and I want to focus on element `myArray[2][1]`, which is `7`.

How can I find the single index of this element, despite the multidimensional array, in the fastest possible algorithm?

i.e. How can I find how many indivisible elements exist before this element?

So in the example above, the previous indivisible elements would be `[0] = 1`, `[1] = 2`, `[2] = 3`, `[3] = 4`, `[4] = 5`, `[5] = 6` making the overall index of `myArray[2][1]`, `6` .

**Edit:**
Even though this example shows the largest dimension being 3-dimensions, is it possible to have an algorithm working for up to n-dimensions.

Ideally a function of the following form:

```
Array.prototype.getOverallIndex(i, j, k, ...)
{
...
return overallIndex;
}
```

Comment: Create a function that takes an array and indexes as arguments and returns the element at the specified indexes:  function getElementAt(arr, i, j) {
    return arr[i][j];
}
console.log(getElementAt(myArray, 2, 1));  // Output: 7

Comment: How would you treat empty arrays? For example, this: `[ [ [1, [ ] , [ [ [ [ ] ] ] ] , 2], 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 10]]`

Comment: please how do you get six as result? please add a detailed calculation for it.

Comment: If the output is `6` (the overall index of the input), then what is the input? `[ 2, 1 ]` (the index path) or `7` (the value)? This would make a difference for repeated values, e.g. for `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]`, I’d expect the overall index of the path `[ 1, 1 ]` (representing `array[1][1]`) to be `3`, but the overall index of the value `2` to be `1` (because it’s found at `array[0][1]`).

Comment: and btw, what is the input and the result of all?

Comment: Will your array always have essentially two values in the first level or is it generally unknown? For example, would you ever have an array like this: `[ [1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7], [8, [9,10], [11, [12, [13, [14, 15, 16] ] ] ], ...  ]` ?

Comment: What is the index of `2` for the array `array` defined by `const cyclic = [ 1 ]; cyclic.push(cyclic); const array = [ 0, cyclic, 2 ];`?

Comment: @fiddlingaway they would be skipped

Comment: @ninascholz it is because 6 elements exist before it, [0][0][0], [0][0][1], [0][1], [1][0], [1][1], [2][0]

Comment: If the empty elements would be skipped, you *might* get away with using [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), but the trick would be in guessing the depth to pass to the `.flat()` method. **EDIT** It would also depend on your setup to adhere to these rules: https://i.imgur.com/ybBsdq1.png

Comment: @ninascholz the input would be the individual indexes and the output would be the overall index

Comment: @fiddlingaway thanks for that, but once I use flat, how would I know the position of the element in the flattened array? I could use find(), but that would only work when there is no identical elements in the array

Comment: Good point - see Roko C. Buljan's answer for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use [Array.prototype.flat(Infinity)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten (any depth) your array
- use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) to get the index of the desired item

Example:

```js
const myArray = [[[1, 2], 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 10]];
const flattened = myArray.flat(Infinity);
console.log(flattened.indexOf(7)) // 6
```

Then, if you want all the indexes of *N*, you could use:

```js
const indexesOf = (arr, num) => arr.flat(Infinity).reduce((a, n, i) => (num === n && a.push(i), a), []);

// Use like:
const myArray = [[[1, 2], 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 10]];
console.log(indexesOf(myArray, 7)) // [6, 7]
```

If in need to get the **max depth** of your array you could use:

```js
const getDepth = (a) => Array.isArray(a) ? 1 + Math.max(0, ...a.map(getDepth)) : 0;

const myArray = [[[1, 2], 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 10]];

// levels deep:
const depth = getDepth(myArray);
console.log(depth); // 3
```

Comment: Ah, but what do we do if we were looking for the second 7? Or nth 7?

Comment: @FiddlingAway added another example that returns an Array of all the indexes where `7` is present in the flattened array. This way you can get the length of appearances and you can then query the *nth*.

Comment: @SUTerliakov you're absolutely right. Corrected as per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could count.

```js
const
    getCount = v => Array.isArray(v)
        ? v.reduce((t, w) => t + getCount(w), 0)
        : 1,
    getCountOfItemsBefore = (array, target) => {
        let i = 0,
            count = 0;

        while (i < target[0]) count += getCount(array[i++]);

        if (target.length > 1 && Array.isArray(array[target[0]])) {
            count += getCountOfItemsBefore(array[target[0]], target.slice(1));
        }
        return count;
    },
    data = [[[1, 2], 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [7, 8], [9, 10]],
    target = [2, 1],
    result = getCountOfItemsBefore(data, target);

console.log(result);
```